# How to add my application autostart in Solaris10

Tags: solaris

I have created my application using java. Also I created RPM which works fine in redhat. In that case I have to put my application.desktop file in startup directory to make my application autostart.

The folder structure is
/etc/xdg/Startup

But in solaris this folder structure doesnot exist. So what I have to do to make my application autostart in solaris10

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify this but if you application is a service, which is supposed to start when the machine starts/restarts, then the answer is to use [Service Management Facility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Management_Facility). Here is some more information on [SMF](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4144-Solaris-Features-Service-Management-Facility-Part-1-Introduction.html).

Answer (score -1):

Solaris 10 uses an old version of gnome with which autostarted applications are defined in /usr/share/gnome/default.session

Have a look to that file header for details and syntax.

OpenSolaris uses /etc/xdg/autostart for that feature.

Comment: Hi there is no /etc/xdg/autostart directory in solaris 10. I have only /usr/share/gnome/default.session.         
I could not find a way to use default.session to make my application auto start

Comment: The way to use default.session is self documented in that file. What did you add and how did it failed ?
And please refrain to give a negative vote when the answer is correct.

Comment: Disappointed to see you fail to answer to my last comment and insist telling my correct answer is not useful to you.